# Overloading abstract virtual method returning template parameter T& as concrete parameter short*&

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, reference, abstract

I wrote an abstract class

```
class A
{
  enum SegmentationType { SOURCE_SEGMENT, DEST_SEGMENT,
              SOURCE_SEGMENT_CONTOUR, DEST_SEGMENT_CONTOUR};

  public:
  virtual const T& getSegmentation(SegmentationType type) =0;
};
```

and derived a class

```
class B : public A<short*>
{
  public:
  const short*& getSegmentation(SegmentationType type);
};
```

from it. However, the compiler complains: "B::getSegmentation overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'A::getSegmentation'". Since the template parameter T of class B is short* and the abstract method returns T&, I expected, that the concrete return value must be a reference to a short pointer, hence short*&. If, for testing purposes, I change the template parameter of B to short and the return value accordingly to short&, then everything works fine.

I would be thankful, if someone could tell me, why this doesn't work.

Comment: just typedef short* to ShortPtr end of problem. The "short *const&" syntax (wich would be the correct answer) is hard to understand for most people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
short* const & getSegmentation(SegmentationType type);
    // ^^^^^ const here
```

`const T&` is "reference to const `T`". Now if `T` is "pointer to `short`", then the return type needs to be "reference to const pointer to `short`", which is `short* const &`. `const short * &` is "reference to pointer to const `short`" - the constness applies to the pointed-to value, rather than the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in B your function returns the reference to the pointer to `const short` while it should return the const reference to the pointer to short. Use

```
short* const& getSegmentation(SegmentationType type);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your issue:

```
short* const & getSegmentation(SegmentationType type);
```

In A you have a const reference to T, and in B you had a reference to `const short`, as it seems to me.